# Generic class containing child of another generic type

Tags: c#, generics

The title may be a bit confusing, but I'm unsure how to phrase it differently.

I have a class of a generic type. I want the class to contain a child of the same class, but with another generic type. Something like this :

```
public class Test<Foo>
{
    private readonly Foo _myFoo;

    public Test<ChildFoo> Child { get; set; }

    public Test(Foo foo)
    {
        _myFoo = foo;
    }
}

public class Impl
{
    public void FooTest()
    {
        var parent = new Test<string>("tester");
        var child = new Test<int>(1234);

        parent.Child = child;
    }
}
```

But I can't have a Child with "ChildFoo" generic. Any other way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a relationship between Foo and ChildFoo?

Comment: @ZoharPeled no. As per the example Foo could be a string, and ChildFoo could be an int

Comment: This seem like a strange design. I suspect that's an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but we lack details to know for sure. Can you share some more information about your actual use-case for such a class?

Comment: I'm playing around with a decision tree. The parent node would have an input of certain type, that will be passed through a requirement/predicate, and if successful, go through its child nodes. I can't really provide any code for that, because it doesn't exist yet, the above is my initial proof of concept.

Comment: If I've correctly understood you're asking if there's a way to create a class which as a property whose type is defined at runtime, after the class itself has been initialized?  As @ZoharPeled mentions, how would the code consuming this know what type to expect / what would your caller look like to handle such code?  NB: If you just want a property that can hold an type, you can always use `object`.

Comment: Well, the only two ways around it that I'm aware of, other than having two type parameters in `Test`, is to either use an `object` as the type of the `child`, or to use a non-generic base class or interface of `Test` as the type of the `child` - both are not that different since it will force the calling code to cast the value of `child` back to the original type (`Test<int>` in your example) - and you lose compiler type safety in the process.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, you're correct. There is now way I would be able to consume this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
public class Test<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly T1 _myFoo;

    public T2 Child { get; set; }

    public Test(T1 foo)
    {
        _myFoo = foo;
    }
}

public class Impl
{
    public void FooTest()
    {
        var parent = new Test<string, Test<int, object>>("tester");
        var child = new Test<int, object>(1234);
        parent.Child = child;
    }
}
```

Since the first solution does not satisfy your needs I have one more idea that involves interface and let's you work with the child as if it was `Test<,>`.

```
public class Test<T1, T2> : ITest where T2 : ITest
{
    private readonly T1 _myFoo;

    public T2 Child { get; set; }

    public void A()
    {
    }

    public void B()
    {
        Child.A();
    }

    public Test(T1 foo)
    {
        _myFoo = foo;
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void A();
    void B();
}

public class Impl
{
    public void FooTest()
    {
        var parent = new Test<string, Test<int, ITest>>("tester");
        var child = new Test<int, ITest>(1234);
        parent.Child = child;
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: If by `ChildFoo` the OP meant that it's a derived class, you'd amend the above to: `public class Test<T1, T2> where T2: T1`

Comment: I also looked at doing it this way. It would work, but that means that my parent would need to know what type it's child is, which is not ideal.

Comment: @WynDiesel. It would always have to. Otherwise how could you use it? That is unless you are prepared to cast it at the consuming site.

Comment: @WynDiesel I edited it the way that might suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this:

```
public class Test<T>
{
    private readonly T _myFoo;

    public Test(T foo)
    {
        _myFoo = foo;
    }
}

public class ParentTest<T, TChild, TChildType> : Test<T> where TChild : Test<TChildType>
{
    TChild Child { get; set; }
}

public class Impl
{
    public void FooTest()
    {
        var parent = new ParentTest<string, Test<int>, int>("tester");
        var child = new Test<int>(1234);

        parent.Child = child;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is correct way, with minimal modification of your code

```
public class Test<Foo,ChildFoo>
{
    private readonly Foo _myFoo;

    public Test<ChildFoo,ChildFoo> Child { get; set; }

    public Test(Foo foo)
    {
        _myFoo = foo;
    }
}

public class Impl
{
    public void FooTest()
    {
        var parent = new Test<string,int>("tester");
        var child = new Test<int,int>(1234);

        parent.Child = child;
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. Test<ChildFoo> doesn't exist

Comment: Now it's just meaningles. What is a Test<ChildFoo, ChildFoo>?

Comment: It is called chaining. It can contains recursive elements like XML does